# Finding a basis of a generalized eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to find a basis for the generalized eigenspace $\ker(A-\operatorname{Id})^3$, where $A\in M_n(C)$ is given by : 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1+i& 2&3-i \\
0 & 1+i & 1 & 2-i\\
0 &-1-i&-1 &-3+i\\
0&1&1&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And $X_A(t)=(t-1)^3(t-i)$.

The solution of this problem states that a basis is : 
$$\{(1,0,0,0)^t,(0,1,-2,1)^t,(0,0,1,0)^t\}$$
But I found :
$$\{(1,0,0,0)^t,(0,1,0,1)^t,(0,0,1,0)^t\}$$
Is it the same basis ? Because $(0,1,-2,1)^t=(0,1,0,1)^t-2(0,0,1,0)^t$ ?
I'm not sure about this...
Any help would be appreciate,

Comment: The *bases* aren't the same, however they both are valid bases of the *same space*.

Comment: Okay, and the argument is the one i gave ?

Comment: That is enough of an argument to convince anyone who is paying attention, but it is technically incomplete as it only shows that $(0,1,-2,1)$ is within the span of the basis you found.  You should also point out the facts that the other two basis vectors in the books solution are also within the span of the basis you found and that both are valid bases of a three dimensional space, thus proving that the space spanned by the first is a subspace of the space spanned by the second and since they are the same dimension implies that the spaces themselves are the same too.

Comment: Remember that for any positive-dimensional subspace of a vector space over an infinite field, there are infinitely many different choices for a basis.  Some are more aesthetically pleasing than others, but they are all valid.  There are many times you would prefer to have as many $1$'s and $0$'s as possible, or prefer to have each basis vector be orthogonal to each other, or them all to be of length $1$, etc... but that is largely preference or contextually dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a result you can rely on to verify whether or not your candidate basis is valid.

**Proposition.** Suppose that $\{v_1,\dotsc, v_d\}$ is a basis of a vector subspace $V\subset\Bbb R^n$ and let $\{w_1,\dotsc, w_d\}\subset\Bbb R^n$. Let $A$ and $B$ be the matrices whose columns are $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ and $\{w_1,\dotsc,w_d\}$ respectively, so
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & \dotsb & v_d\end{bmatrix} & B &= \begin{bmatrix}w_1 & \dotsb & w_d\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Then $\{w_1,\dotsc,w_d\}$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if there is an invertible matrix $P$ satisfying $AP=B$.

In your situation, the matrices $A$ and $B$ are given by
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right] & B &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Is there an invertible $P$ satisfying $AP=B$?

*Hint.* There is and the matrix looks like this
$$
P = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & \ast & 0 \\
0 & \ast & 0 \\
0 & \ast & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Can you find the second column of $P$?